# Significance of 4 Teveis in Judaism

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

Is the 4th day of the Month of Teveis significant in Judaism? Looking for answers as to what characteristics (historical, numerological or otherwise) that is commemorated by or significant to Judaism on this date. It can include both positive and negative significance. It can also include Yarzheits of well known personalities that are themselves significant to Judaism, or milestones in their lives (such as birthdays) that are currently or were celebrated within Judaism.

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

All interesting answers will be up voted. Best answer will be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yahrzeit of Rav Gershon Chanoch Leiner Zatzal of Radzin - the Baal Techeles